# C# Html Agility Pack dd and dt tags parse problem

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, dd

I'm trying to parse this field, but can't get it to work. Current attempt:

HTML:

```
<div class="movie_data">
<dl>
    <dt><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1302011/">IMDB</a>:</dt>
    <dd>8.0 / 10</dd>
    <dt>Zvrst:</dt>
    <dd><a href="/sl/kino?t=&amp;g=1&amp;actual=1">komedija</a>, <a href="/sl/kino?t=&amp;g=14&amp;actual=1">animirani</a>, <a href="/sl/kino?t=&amp;g=21&amp;actual=1">družinski</a></dd> 
    <dt>Trajanje:</dt>
    <dd>90 min</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

My code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocTusCelje = web.Load(my_link_to); 
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode nodeOcena = htmlDocTusCelje.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='movie_data']/dt/dd[0]");
labelOcena.Text = nodeOcena.InnerText;
```

I need to parse only the inner text from the `<dd>` tag, but I get an exception: `NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I tried with `SelectNodes` and a foreach loop - same story. Please help me out of this error.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with your xpath:

1. The index should be 1-based, not 0-based.
2. You wrote `dt` instead of `dl`.

If the xpath query cannot find such nodes it returns `null`, which is causing your error when trying to use `nodeOcena`.

This seems to work:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='movie_data']/dl/dd[1]");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it does not work either, still same error.

Comment: @Strausa - I've tested before posting... Here's my complete code: http://pastebin.com/TCrghyv3 (with the HTML on http://jsbin.com/anodo5) - Does that give you the same error?

Comment: Yes, It works! It was problem with my link, i got it from xml <link> tag an there was different link so It does not find this xpath.